# How to change characters in TextView on touch?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a TextView with text. How to change characters when user hover them with touch? I need to change only characters that were hovered.

Comment: please mentioned what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use textview's on Touch listener to change the text

```
tv.setOnTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener());

public class CustomTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch(motionEvent.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // Action you you want on finger down.
                Toast.makeText(this,"onTouch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // Action you you want on finger up
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can write your code on ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP

Hope this might help you

Comment: I know that, but I need to work with every character separately(change hovered character, change its color).

Comment: tv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { Layout layout = ((TextView) v).getLayout(); int x = (int)event.getX(); int y = (int)event.getY(); if (layout!=null){ int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y); int offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x); Log.v("index", ""+offset); } return true; } });.    Try this

Comment: That looks fine. Thanks!